# how to calculate google backlinks using php

Tags: php

i want to create my own tool for back-links calculation using PHP. is there any api to fetech the data for back links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full implementation in PHP would look something like this:

```
<?php
$domain = "example.com"; // Enter your domain here.

$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=large&"
    . "q=link:".$domain;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $domain);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($body);
$urls = array();
foreach($json->responseData->results as $result) // Loop through the objects in the result
    $urls[] = $result->unescapedUrl;             // and add the URL to the array.
?>
```

Basically you edit the domain variable at the top and it will fill the `$urls` array with unescaped URLs linking to the domain.

EDIT: I've edited the link to return 8 results. For more, you'll have to parse the pages and loop through them with the start parameter. See the [Class Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_intro_fonje) for more information.

Comment: using this code i am not getting the right result as link:example.com

Answer (score 1):

Run a Google search with the URL prefixed by `link:` - for instance, `link:www.mydomain.com`.

While Google does provide a more specific backlink overview in their Webmaster Tools area ([more info](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/02/discover-your-links.html)), I'm not sure they provide an external API for it.

Comment: Use the Google Search AJAX API: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje

Answer (score 1):

since the question is "how to use in php code?" I assume you want to process on the server side as opposed to ajax on the client side. So use the Google URL link: hack in combination with curl 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: JSON is not limited to AJAX. You can also parse JSON with PHP, Dav's link contains an example.

Comment: I am not saying it is, was clarifying to the op that can be used server side. I think the important part was using curl which you gladly took from my response.

Comment: Actually, that came from the API dav linked. Everything but the foreach was copied from there.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a PHP class with many more options, that you can use: http://code.google.com/p/seostats/

Answer (score 1):

```
function load_content ($url, $auth = true,$auth_param) {
          $curl = curl_init();
          $uagent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
          if ($auth){
                  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$auth_param);
          }
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
          $content = curl_exec($curl);
          //$header = curl_getinfo($curl);
          curl_close($curl);
          $res['msg'] = "";//$header;
          $res['content'] = $content;
          return $res;
 }

function google_indexed($url){
          $html = load_content ($url,false,"");
          return $html;
 }
```

Example:

```
<?php
 $domain = "google.com";
 $indexed["google"] = google_indexed("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:$domain");
```

http://alex-kurilov.blogspot.com/2012/09/backlink-checker-google-php-example.html

Answer (score 0):

For finding External links to the page : (external backlinks)

```
    <?php
        $url = "any url";
    $result_in_html = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/search?q=link:{$url}");
    if (preg_match('/Results .*? of about (.*?) from/sim', $result_in_html, $regs))
    {
        $indexed_pages = trim(strip_tags($regs[1])); //use strip_tags to remove bold tags
        echo ucwords($domain_name) . ' Has <u>' . $indexed_pages . '</u>external links to page';
    } elseif (preg_match('/About (.*?) results/sim', $result_in_html, $regs))
    {
        $indexed_pages = trim(strip_tags($regs[1])); //use strip_tags to remove bold tags
        echo ucwords($domain_name) . ' Has <u>' . $indexed_pages . '</u> external links to page';
    } else
    {
        echo ucwords($domain_name) . ' Has Not Been Indexed @ Google.com!';
    }
    ?>
```

And to find internal backlinks :

```
    <?php
    $url = "any url";
    $result_in_html = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/search?q=site:{$url}");
    if (preg_match('/Results .*? of about (.*?) from/sim', $result_in_html, $regs))
    {
        $indexed_pages = trim(strip_tags($regs[1])); //use strip_tags to remove bold tags
        echo ucwords($domain_name) . ' Has <u>' . $indexed_pages . '</u> internal links to page';
    } elseif (preg_match('/About (.*?) results/sim', $result_in_html, $regs))
    {
        $indexed_pages = trim(strip_tags($regs[1])); //use strip_tags to remove bold tags
        echo ucwords($domain_name) . ' Has <u>' . $indexed_pages . '</u> internal links to page';
    } else
    {
        echo ucwords($domain_name) . ' Has Not Been Indexed @ Google.com!';
    }
    ?>
```